# On Code-Coverage

Tags: java, code-coverage

Language : JAVA

I am trying to use a test code to carry out code coverage analysis over a main code. I want to know how much does this  main code use up the test code. How to make it possible?

Comment: Use ecobetura in eclipse for code coverage - http://ecobertura.johoop.de/

Answer (score 1):

Following is the list(not exhaustive) of code coverage tools for Java:

- JCov
- JaCoCo
- Clover

You can find further here : [Java Code Coverage Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools)